# How can I rebuild an azure search index on prod?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

how can we change index schema on prod with minimun outages? is there a way to "Swap" services(like we do on web roles) and mantain functionalities when re-creating the index?

Comment: When you say rebuilding an index, do you mean updating an existing index (by adding more fields for example) or create a new index based on an existing index?

Comment: Yes, doing some change on the index that needs to be recreated, for example deleting some field or changing a field type

Comment: Deleting existing fields or changing its type are not currently supported by Azure Search today. You'll need to create a new index from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, I know so I was thinking if there is a way to have 2 instances of the index in case you need to create the index from scratch(to not lose the search while indexing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this via application configuration as follows:

1. Make sure the app depends on configuration for deciding which index to talk to.
2. Build a new index
3. Update app config to use the new index

Please vote for relevant Azure Search UserVoice suggestions:

1. [Support schema changes with reindexing](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/11143359-support-schema-changes-with-automated-reindexing)
2. [Support swapping indexes](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328647-support-swapping-indexes)